# How to connect Oracle Database to Oracle Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm developing my small project using Oracle Database and Developer. When I create a new connection, this problem always show up:
[image]

I can not create connection.

I check services, and can't find OracleDBHome1Listener, what can I do to fix this?
[image]

run lsnrctl status shown this:

[image]

Comment: What this command shows you: `lsnrctl status`?

Comment: I post picture below, many thanks

Comment: LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 10-AUG-2021 21:16:21

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.23.144.1)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00505: Operation timed out
   64-bit Windows Error: 60: Unknown error

Comment: Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory

Comment: Your SQL Developer connection is trying to reach localhost; your lsnrctl is trying to reach 172.23.144.1. It's unclear if this has ever worked - but I would guess that you have rebooted and been given a different IP address (via DHCP). Try re-running netca. If you are only ever going to connect locally, use localhost consistently when configuring the listener. Otherwise you need a fixed IP, or a host name that can be resolved to the current DHCP address, so it still works across reboots.

Comment: What version of oracle you are using? Can you run ```tnsping localhost``` and feedback the result. your oracle server may be down, try start it :  ```lsnrctl start```.

Comment: I know server is v 19c. :).

Comment: Thank guys, I had resolve this problem, I change host in listener.ora to localhost, run command lsnrctl stop. lsnrctl start, lsnrctl services to get all service, add another SID in SID list in listener.ora ; and my LARGE_POOL_SIZE was too small, that got all this problem, solve it with adding DIRECT_HANDOFF_TTC_LISTENER=OFF in listener.ora and free some dishspace